# Firebase simulator Read gives permission denied?

Tags: firebase

My firebase data looks like this-

[image: Database]

My security rules are-

```
{

  "rules": {

    "users": {
      "fred": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
      },
      "wilma": {
        ".read": "auth.id == '1'",
        ".write":true
      },
      "$other": {
        "name": {
          ".read": true,
          ".write": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the problem is in my URL. I don't know how to use auth query parameter in REST APIs

Comment: You need to click the authenticate button. Do not put auth=... into your URL under step 2.

Answer (score 1):

First click on Authenticate button.

Path you should enter is `/users/wilma`