# Firebase simulate read denied

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

In my firebase project, I have implemented Google Authentication.

My firebase rules looks like the following:

```
{
  "rules": {
      "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The database has the following snapshot:
[image]

Everytime I try to simulate. Firebase says that the "Simulate read denied".

[image]

Any ideas that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase simulator Read gives permission denied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626108/firebase-simulator-read-gives-permission-denied)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I realised the problem. I was accessing "/users" but instead, I should be accessing "/users/$uid" to simulate rule.

Comment: when i try and type that into the location field of the rules playground, it states that it is a invalud location. doesnt like the $uid part

Comment: @Jono, you need to remove $ these days, so `"/users/uid"` will do.